# why is my while loop skipping over the first line of my file

Tags: bash, file, loops

I have a file with 64 lines in it. I want to extract the first and fifth word of each line to a new file, so i have a while loop running to do this. However, my output file just has 63 lines, and after checking I see that the first line is missing. This is the code I have:

```
tail -n +9 table.$1 > tab.$1

while read -r
do
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $5}' > rtable.$1

done < tab.$1
```

The tail at the beginning is to get the 64 lines I want from a larger file. However it is not the issue as the tab.$1 file is fine, but rtable.$1 file which is shorter.

Comment: what are you reading form `tab.$1` ? what is the input file for `awk` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your input file is consumed by `read -r`. All remaining lines are then processed by `awk` and written to `rtable.$1`.

The next iteration of your `while` loop then ends because `read -r` has nothing to read anymore. And what a good thing that is too, because otherwise `awk > rtable.$1` would have run again and overwritten your output file.

Solution: Just remove the loop.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $5}' > rtable.$1 < tab.$1
```

You could even get rid of `tab.$1` entirely:

```
tail -n +9 table.$1 | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $5}' > rtable.$1
```

Answer (score 1):

@melpomene beat me to it, but I'll add explanation that is too long for a comment.

- `awk`, by default, reads the full contents of standard input.  That is the case here, since your script does not give `awk` an input filename.
- The redirection of `while ... done < tab.$1` connects `tab.$1` to standard input for not only the `while`, but everything in the `while`.  Therefore, between `read` and `awk`, only one of them can get each line of input.
- As @melpomene said, `read` takes one line, and then `awk` pulls the rest (its default behaviour).